# contourf is not reflecting ListedColormap with boundaries

Tags: python, matplotlib, contourf

Is possible to apply custom colorbar with boundaries to graph? For example to `contourf`?

Because I can change boundaries of `colorbar`, but `contourf` is not reflecting these boundaries.

```
colors = ["#ffffff", "#FFD8CA", "#FFAB98", "#FF7765", "#FF3E33", "#FF0000"]
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)

m = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap)
m.set_array(zi)
m.set_clim(min(z), max(z))
plt.colorbar(m, boundaries=[min(z), 0.35, 0.7, 1.05, 1.4, min(z)])
plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, 6, cmap=cmap,alpha=0.7, vmin=min(z), vmax=max(z))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 6 boundary values, you need 5 colors.
The boundaries are the `levels` of your contour. Specify this via the `levels` argument.
Then the colorbar will automatically be correct.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors

x,y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-3,3), np.linspace(-3,3))
z = np.exp(-x**2-y**2)*1.5+0.2

colors = ["white", "mistyrose", "lightcoral", "firebrick", "black"]
cmap= matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors)
boundaries=[z.min(), 0.35, 0.7, 1.05, 1.4, z.max()]

m = plt.contourf(x, y, z, levels = boundaries, cmap=cmap)

plt.colorbar(m, spacing="proportional")
plt.show()
```

[image]